# XSL: transform a XML file with another to filter it

Tags: xml, xslt, filter, transform, xslt-2.0

Its me again, but this time i have a real problem...
I have one XML, and i have to transform it in another XML by using a filter of another XML

**File_in.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
    <root>
        <item>
            <server>001023541</server>
            <name>P1</name>
            <desc>Production</desc>
            <status>1</status>
            <ram>1024</ram>
            <hdd>8 To</hdd>
        </item>
        <item>
            <server>201012345</server>
            <name>P2</name>
            <desc>Production</desc>
            <status>4</status>
            <ram>2048</ram>
            <hdd>8 To</hdd>
        </item>
        <item>
            <server>120332416</server>
            <name>P1</name>
            <desc>Production</desc>
            <status>2</status>
            <ram>8196</ram>
            <hdd>8 To</hdd>
        </item>
    </root>
```

---

And another XML:

**filter.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
    <Filtre>
        <Bloc5>
            <Part1>
                <EAN>001023541</EAN>
                <EAN>012356549</EAN>
                <EAN>012356559</EAN>
                <EAN>012356569</EAN>
            </Part1>
            <Part2>
                <EAN>201012345</EAN>
                <EAN>201012346</EAN>
                <EAN>201012347</EAN>
            </Part2>
        </Bloc5>
    </Filtre>
```

---

If /root/item/server matches with an element of /Filtre/Bloc5/Part1/EAN, i replace

```
        <item>
            <server>001023541</server>
            <name>P1</name>
            <desc>Production</desc>
            <status>1</status>
            <ram>1024</ram>
            <hdd>8 To</hdd>
        </item>
```

by

```
        <item>
            <server>MAIN</server>
            <status>PRODUCTION</status>
        </item>
```

---

otherwise if /root/item/server matches with an element of /Filtre/Bloc5/Part2/EAN, i replace

```
        <item>
            <server>201012345</server>
            <name>P2</name>
            <desc>Production</desc>
            <status>4</status>
            <ram>2048</ram>
            <hdd>8 To</hdd>
        </item>
```

by

```
        <item>
            <server>BACKUP</server>
            <status>STOPPED</status>
        </item>
```

---

and the other are automatically replaced like:

```
        <item>
            <server>120332416</server>
            <name>P1</name>
            <desc>Production</desc>
            <status>2</status>
            <ram>8196</ram>
            <hdd>8 To</hdd>
        </item>
```

by

```
        <item>
            <name>OFFLINE</name>
            <desc>Production</desc>
        </item>
```

---

I get the name of the XML (used to filter) by this way:

```
            <!-- filter settings -->
            <xsl:param name="filter_xml" />
            <xsl:variable name="filter" select="document('$filter_xml')" />
```

And there is my code :

```
        <xsl:for-each select="root/item">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="index-of(($filter/Filtre/Bloc5/Part1/EAN), ./server)">
                <item>
                    <server>MAIN</server>
                    <status>PRODUCTION</status>
                </item>
                </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="index-of(($filter/Filtre/Bloc5/Part2/EAN), ./server)" >
                <item>
                    <server>BACKUP</server>
                    <status>STOPPED</status>
                </item>
            </xsl:when >
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <item>
                    <name>OFFLINE</name>
                    <desc>Production</desc>
                </item>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

But this does not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much cleaner, simpler and efficient solution is to use template matching instead of tortuous  branching. I am assuming XSLT 2.0 because you did not tag your question with the XSLT version number, but if you need XSLT 1.0, then adjustments can easily be made.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:variable name="filter" select="document('filter.xml')/*" />

<xsl:template match="/" >
 <root>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*/item" />
 </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[server=$filter/Bloc5/Part1/EAN]" >
  <item>
    <server>MAIN</server>
    <status>PRODUCTION</status>
  </item>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[server=$filter/Bloc5/Part2/EAN]" >
  <item>
    <server>BACKUP</server>
    <status>STOPPED</status>
  </item>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item" >
  <item>
    <name>OFFLINE</name>
    <desc>Production</desc>
  </item>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

## Update: Icing on the cake

Thanks for your acceptance. As icing on the cake, you could also replace the first two item templates with this *ONE* more generic and extensible template. But it's debatable whether it is more simpler or more complex.

Alternative generic item template (only works for XSLT 2.0) ...

```
<xsl:template match="item[server=$filter/Bloc5/*/EAN]" >
  <xsl:variable name="part-no"
    select="substring-after(local-name(($filter/Bloc5/*[EAN=current()/server])[1]),
            'Part') cast as xs:integer" />
  <xsl:copy>
    <server><xsl:value-of select="('MAIN'      ,'BACKUP' )[$part-no]" /></server>
    <status><xsl:value-of select="('PRODUCTION','STOPPED')[$part-no]" /></status>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things that you need to adjust:

1. The path for the `document()` needs to be the value of the filter variable. You are currently passing the string "$filter".  You need to change
   `<xsl:variable name="filter" select="document('$filter_xml')" />` 
   to `<xsl:variable name="filter" select="document($filter_xml)" />`
2. The `contains()` function expects string inputs for each of the parameters. In order to evaluate the `contains()` test against each of the filter's `EAN`, perform the test inside of a predicate filter on the `EAN` elements. For example, change: `<xsl:when test="index-of(($filter/Filtre/Bloc5/Part1/EAN), ./server)">` to  `<xsl:when test="$filter/Filtre/Bloc5/Part1/EAN[contains(., ./server)]">`.  If anything matches, the result will be at least one `EAC`, which will evaluate to `true()` in the test.

Applied to an example XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="filter_xml" />
    <xsl:variable name="filter" select="document($filter_xml)" />

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:for-each select="root/item">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$filter/Filtre/Bloc5/Part1/EAN[contains(., ./server)]">
                    <item>
                        <server>MAIN</server>
                        <status>PRODUCTION</status>
                    </item>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$filter/Filtre/Bloc5/Part2/EAN[contains(., ./server)]" >
                    <item>
                        <server>BACKUP</server>
                        <status>STOPPED</status>
                    </item>
                </xsl:when >
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <item>
                        <name>OFFLINE</name>
                        <desc>Production</desc>
                    </item>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, i looked on Muench method, but this method i better for my work.